# When is a UI Element assigned to thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I know I have seen an article or SO on this before, but cannot seem to find it now. I ran into a problem helping a coworker write a test that was checking UI actions that were occurring across multiple threads (I realize the problems here...that is not what I want to focus on at the moment :)). The code looks similar to this kind of pseudocode:

```
[RequiresSTA]
Test
{
  var tb = new Textbox();
  tb.DoSomethingAsyncAndThenUpdateTB() //This is done via tb.SetValue being called
}
```

...

```
DoSomethingAsyncAndThenUpdateTB()
{
  var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bw.DoWork += ...Do Stuff...
  bw.RunWorkerCompleted += { tb.Text = "foo";}
}
```

The problem I am running into is that the `OnComplete` is throwing a cross thread exception. However, everything should have been created on the STA thread. I BELIEVE the problem is that UI elements get attached to their thread not on creation, but at a later point....and my textbox ends up attaching to a thread that isn't the STA? Or maybe the backgroundworker?

**The question:**

When does a UI element actually get attached to a thread?

Comment: `OnComplete` will not run in the TextBoxes' thread. You need to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

Comment: OnComplete  doesn't exist on BackgroundWorker, do you mean RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, that is why I said pseudocode

Comment: Don't create the BGW on any other thread than the main thread (which is what Servy is alluding to).  i.e. the "thread" you're talking about is the thread that creates the BGW.

Answer (score 2):

So first off, there isn't just one STA thread.  Any thread can be created as *an* STA thread when it's created.  The UI thread needs to be an STA thread, but not all STA threads are UI threads.

Next, you have the issue that `BackgroundWorker` needs to have some way of knowing what the UI thread is.  It's not magic that it's able to marshal certain events to the UI thread.  What it does is it looks at the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` in its constructor.  It then captures the value of that context, and uses it later as it's definition of the context to post all non-work events to.  If you create the BGW outside of the UI thread then it's not able to marshal back to the UI thread later.

If you have an STA thread that you are using as your UI thread, but you haven't set a value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`, then the BGW won't be able to do its thing.

As for the question of:

> When does a UI element actually get attached to a thread?

In its constructor.

Comment: Hrmmm, I could have swore that it was not in the constructor. Eric Lippert or somebody wrote something....I thought..Anywho, the bgw is being created by a call through a dependency property set from the main thread...maybe Dependency properties create their own threads...but I didn't think so

Comment: @JustinPihony Check the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` where the textbox is created, and where the BGW is created.  It should be non-null in both places, and be a reference to the same context.  It's possible the UI framework used in your testing framework doesn't create that context, if so, add your own by setting the current context yourself.

Comment: @JustinPihony It's possible certain other controls attach themselves to a thread at a later point, but I'm pretty sure that's not the case for Textbox.  In either case, my guess is that it's not your issue, your issue is much more likely in configuring the BGW, not the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Each ui element implements DependencyObject, which implements abstract class DispatcherObject.. When DispatcherObject is created it assigns current dispatcher to the DispatcherObject..
Later on, whenever you access any property of the UI element, there is a validation that checks if you are accessing it from UI thread.

This si done in VerifyAccess

```
/// <summary>Enforces that the calling thread has access to this <see cref="T:System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject" />.</summary>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">the calling thread does not have access to this <see cref="T:System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject" />.</exception>
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public void VerifyAccess()
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = this._dispatcher;
        if (dispatcher != null)
        {
            dispatcher.VerifyAccess();
        }
    }
```

If a calling thread is not the one associated with dispatcher, then exception is thrown

```
public void VerifyAccess()
```

{
    if (!this.CheckAccess())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("VerifyAccess"));
    }
}

This is called **Thread Affinity**